# Display List items horizontally not vertically

Tags: php, html, css, laravel

I want to display books list in a horizontal way not in a vertical way..

Here is my foreach loop in book_view.blade.php

```
@foreach ($books as $book)
<div class="d-inline p-2">
<div class="w3-card-4 w3-dark-grey" style="width:50%">
<div class="w3-container w3-center">
<h5 style="color:#3490dc;"> {{ $book->title }}</h5>
<?php 
$books = (json_decode($book->img))[0]->download_link;
?>
<img src="{{ Voyager::image( $books ) }}" alt="images"/>
<br/>
<h6>Auther: <span class="badge badge-secondary">{{ $book->auther }}</h6>
<h6>Published: {{ $book->published }}<h6>
<h6 style="color:#3490dc;">ISBN: {{ $book->isbn }}</h6>

  <div class="w3-section"> 
  </div>
  <?php 
  $books = (json_decode($book->pdf))[0]->download_link;
  ?>enter code here
  <a href="{{ Voyager::image( $books ) }}" class="btn btn-primary">Read Book</a>
  <a href="{{ url('/checkout') }}" class="btn btn-success">Buy Book</a>
  <br/>
</div>
</div>

    @endforeach
```

Here is the image  of the current output...

[image]

Comment: do you have an image of the current output and expected output? `d-inline` implies that it's already output in a horizontal (i.e. "like you would read a text paragraph") format.

Comment: I have the image of the current output bt...

Comment: Just updated my question by adding the out of the code

Comment: do you want to show all the books in horizontal view or its something like  pair or 3 and next line ?

Answer (score -1):

You are missing a closing `div`. You should format your code and make it more readable then you will spot errors like this faster:

```html
@foreach ($books as $book)
<div class="d-inline p-2">
  <div class="w3-card-4 w3-dark-grey" style="width:50%">
    <div class="w3-container w3-center">
      <h5 style="color:#3490dc;"> {{ $book->title }}</h5>
      <?php $books = (json_decode($book->img))[0]->download_link; ?>
      <img src="{{ Voyager::image( $books ) }}" alt="images"/>
      <br/>
      <h6>Auther: <span class="badge badge-secondary">{{ $book->auther }}</h6>
      <h6>Published: {{ $book->published }}<h6>
      <h6 style="color:#3490dc;">ISBN: {{ $book->isbn }}</h6>
      <div class="w3-section"> 
      </div>
      <?php $books = (json_decode($book->pdf))[0]->download_link; ?>
      enter code here
      <a href="{{ Voyager::image( $books ) }}" class="btn btn-primary">Read Book</a>
      <a href="{{ url('/checkout') }}" class="btn btn-success">Buy Book</a>
      <br/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>  <!-- You are missing this -->
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, you are right i did miss a divide taq but i still got the same results...will appreciate any further help

Comment: @Daniel update the code so we can check

Comment: I copied and reused the above code you apdated by adding a div taq to replace my foreach loop...i still got the data in a vertiacal order

Comment: @Daniel can you create the grid with the same HTML and post the CSS as well? On a codepen or jsfiddle so we can check. Or if it's deployed somewhere we can check